# How to pass different arguments to __new__ vs __init__ without a metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I have a simple base class that instantiates to one of two child classes:

```
class Base:
    def __new__(cls, select):
        return super().__new__(Child1 if select == 1 else Child2)

    def __init__(self, select):
        self.select = select

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.select})'

class Child1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('One')

class Child2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Two')
```

This currently raises an error because the child `__init__` method takes no argument while the parent `__new__` does:

```
>>> Base(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I can solve this by overriding `type.__call__` in a new metaclass, but I want to keep `type` as my metaclass.

I can also add `select` or `*args` as a parameter to the child `__init__` methods. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing the same of allowing a child `__init__` to run with different parameters than the parent `__new__` accepts?

Comment: `return super().__new__(Child1 if select == 1 else Child2)` looks a bit suspicious.  Is this just for the sake of this example or is this in the actual code as well?

Comment: @DeepSpace. Highly contrived, but very representative example. I am trying to load a file format with many versions. The version does not affect the user interface: user instantiates a `Base` object with the path, and I use polymorphism to load the contents once the common header with the version number has been parsed. `Base()` needs to return one of the (private) `Child*` implementations transparently to the user. I can trivially use a metaclass here, but it causes some minor problems down the line. Hence the desire to keep `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it's not possible, at least with more 'elegant' way than metaclasses. In older python there were possibility to pass arguments to `super().__new__` but they were never used actually, so that behaviour [was deprecated](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/076841.html) and removed at all later.

> The message means just what it says. :-) There's no point in calling
> object.__new__() with more than a class parameter, and any code that
> did so was just dumping those args into a black hole.
>
> The only time when it makes sense for object.__new__() to ignore extra
> arguments is when it's not being overridden, but __init__ *is* being
> overridden -- then you have a completely default **new** and the
> checking of constructor arguments is relegated to **init**.
>
> The purpose of all this is to catch the error in a call like
> object(42) which (again) passes an argument that is not used. This is
> often a symptom of a bug in your program.